# What locks do each locking hint produce?

Tags: sql-server, locking

I have read a lot of articles about [locking and locking hints](https://sql-articles.com/articles/general/locks-a-locking-hints/). That resource and [this one](https://www.sqlshack.com/locking-sql-server/) have a very helpful matrix of the compatibility of these modes. Very nice. It shows how Intent exclusive (IX) is not compatible with Shared with intent exclusive (SIX), Shared with intent exclusive (SIX) is not compatible with itself! but Intent exclusive (IX) is compatible with itself. I am getting contention between 2 select statements, one using SIX and the other IX. I would like to see what would happen if both were IX, but I don't know what, if any, locking hint I can use to produce this. Suggestions? Bad idea and just let SQL Server do it's thing even if it results in deadlocks? Beyond this one example, I would like to see a matrix of "this locking hint produces these locks" if it exists.

Comment: "Bad idea and just let SQL Server do it's thing even if it results in deadlocks" is about right. If you have a specific deadlock problem then investigate that, don't jump ahead. Make sure all your queries have covering indexes, including updates, deletes and foreign keys.

Comment: So you're not interested in knowing what lock a locking hint produces? Do you never use locking hints? I'm not sure why this is even a bad question to ask.

Comment: @John - you suggested that it might be a rabbit hole right in the question, so you shouldn't be surprised when someone agrees with your own assessment. Specific to your problem, the SIX lock implies some sort of modification going on (which may or may not be the query that's showing up in your deadlock but could be another query in the same transaction). That said, a definitive guide to how locking gets changed by which query hints sounds like a great blog post!

Comment: The question as a whole is too open-ended. Might be worth reading up about locks and asking a more specific question. As to actually adding locking hints, my point stands. You need to start off with showing your actual situation: the tables (including indexes), the query, the query plan (please share via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan) and show what locking/blocking you are seeing.

Comment: The links I provide list all of the locks and all of the locking hints but do not relate the hints to the locks. That's not a very broad question, it is? I  could make it more specific like, if I use the UPDLOCK locking hint, what kind of lock will that produce on a select. Would that be better? There are not that many possibilities.

Comment: Then I'm confused about what you are asking. Do you want to know "how to resolve a specific locking/blocking issue" then provide debugging info as asked. Or do you want to know "which locking hints refer to which locks" mostly irrelevant as they simply don't exist, apart from `XLOCK` and possibly `UPDLOCK`, the rest refer to the scope `ROWLOCK` `TABLOCK` or isolation level `SERIALIZABLE` etc. These are two completely different questions: a question about blocking is probably not going to be resolved just by splattering hints about.